# How to pass Comma Delimited String to JDBC Query in Mule

Tags: mule

Here I need to pass dynamic multiple customer ID's to the select query in mule. So i have come up with a comma seperated string which holds my customer ID's for ex: **String custid=1001,1002** .I'm using groovy evalutor to fetch the string value to the JDBC query.But I'm receiving an empty payload after executing the query. Also for a single value string like **String Custid =1001** i'm getting the desired result. So In Mule  whether it appends a single quotes for the string like **'1001,1002'**, which causes this issue?.

Please help me to resolve this issue .Also please let me know whether there is any other approaches which can be followed to resolve this issue ?

Here is my code snippet:

```
<jdbc:query key="getCustID" value="SELECT CUSTID,CUSTTYPE FROM CUSTINFO WHERE CUSTID IN  (#[groovy:payload.custid]) "/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mule replaces expressions, like `#[groovy:payload.custid]` with bound parameters, so this is why it doesn't work: the coma separated values are replaced as a single parameter.

I don't have a great solution for what you want to do. One approach would be to register the query with the IDs list already resolved on the [JDBC connector `queries` map](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/transport/jdbc/JdbcConnector.html#getQueries%28%29) just before using it. You would generate a unique query name (like a UUID) to ensure it's used only by the current thread and you would also need to remove it from the `queries` map after usage to avoid memory leaks.

This is very hacky though, hopefully someone else will have a better answer...